# spacenav_node tutorial help

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all

I tried to go through spacenav_node two basic tutorials. I was able to echo the 6DOF joystick on topic /spacenav/joy. The reading from the joystick is correct. However when I run the turtle sim, the turtle did not move at all. After double print out the rxgraph, I found turtle_teleop node is subscripting topic /joy[unknown type]. I guess it might be the bug.

So I tried to changed file .../spacenav_node/src/spacenav_node.cpp, make it published /joy topic instead.

> > ros::Publisher joy_pub = node_handle.advertisejoy::Joy("/joy", 2);

It does not help. node spacenav_node still publish /spacenav/joy. I am new to ROS. I guess there is some easy and right way to do this. Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated. thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10140/spacenav_node-tutorial-help/) by [jayson ding](https://answers.ros.org/users/492/jayson-ding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not change the code. Use remapping instead.

e.g. start turtle_teleop with joy:=spacenav_joy.

You should read the documentation about topics and remapping to understand what's going on.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0